# First use of corner quotes for Gödel numbers

Tags: reference-request, notation, mathematical-logic, logic

Who first used the corner quotes, ⌜ and ⌝, or $\texttt{\Godelnum}$ with Sam Buss's macro, for the notion of Gödel number?

[Quine introduced corner quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-quotation), but did not use them for the notion of Gödel numbers.

The corner quotes were used for Gödel numbers by Joseph R. Shoenfield, *Mathematical Logic*, 1967, as from page 122.

[image]

The Corner quotes are used prevalently in provability logic, and in other areas of logic. Two important citations are Craig Smorynski, The Incompleteness Theorems, in *Handbook of Mathematical Logic*, as from 1st edition 1979; and Paanu Raatikainen, [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/sup1.html), in Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy.

Edit: I do not find the corner quotes in Martin Davies, The Undecidable, or in the books by Moztowski or Kleene.

Comment: I agree with your last edit: I've tried a check on a quite huge number of textbooks from '60s and I've found no similar use. So, I've no evidence when the original Quine's quotes, used in [ML (1951, revised edition)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Mathematical_Logic_Revised_Edition/5glxwVt_srEC) in the context of Incompleteness but with a different meaning (see page 314), has been used for the  "godel numbering function" before Shoenfield (if any). For example, Raymond Smullyan, Formal Systems (1961) uses $g(x)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for the research! You may offer an answer.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA May you compare with the answer offered to the same question here? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430869/first-use-of-corner-quotes-for-g%c3%b6del-numbers/431347#431347 I will check the references provided there, tomorrow Brazilian time.